# input multiple value to one row in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 pieces of the column, which I will inserting in one table in my database. The name of each form like this:

```
<h3><?= $title; ?></h3><?php echo form_open("admin/artikel/buat/");?>
<table width="95%">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Pilih Referensi Jurnal</b></td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="IDJurnal" id="IDJurnal" value="<?php echo $IDJurnal; ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="<?php echo $volume; ?>" readonly="readonly"  class="sedang" />
        <?php echo anchor_popup('admin/artikel/popup', 'Referensi Jurnal', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Kategori</b></td>
    <td>
        <?php
            echo form_dropdown('IDKategori', $kategori) . "";
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><strong>Judul</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="judul" class="panjang"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="125"><strong>Pengarang</strong></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="pengarang" class="panjang">
            <input type="text" name="pengarang" class="panjang">
            <input type="text" name="pengarang" class="panjang">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Abstract</b></td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $data = array('name' => 'abstract');
            echo $this->ckeditor->editor($data['name']);
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Simpan">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="Batal" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
            echo form_close();
?>
```

i want inserting the value from each form name to my sql table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `pengarang`(
`IDPengarang` INT(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IDArtikel` INT(11)NOT NULL,
`nama_pengarang` VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`IDPengarang`))ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

in my model like this:

```
function addArtikel() {
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data = array(
        'IDJurnal' => $this->input->post('IDJurnal'),
        'IDKategori' => $this->input->post('IDKategori'),
        'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
        'abstract' => $this->input->post('abstract'),
        'created_time' => $now,
        'created_by' => $_SESSION['username']
    );
    // $data1 = array(
        // 'IDJurnal' => $this->input->post('IDJurnal'),
        // 'IDKategori' => $this->input->post('IDKategori'),
        // 'judul' => $this->input->post('judul'),
        // 'abstract' => $this->input->post('abstract'),
        // 'created_time' => $now,
        // 'created_by' => $_SESSION['username']
    // );
    // $data2 = array(
        // 'IDArtikel' => $this->input->post('IDArtikel'),
        // 'nama_pengarang' => $this->input->post('pengarang')
    // );

    $this->db->insert('artikel', $data);
    // $this->db->insert_batch('artikel', $data1);
    // $this->db->insert_batch('pengarang', $data1);
}
```

in my controller

```
function buat() {
    if ($this->input->post('judul')) {
        $this->MArtikel->addArtikel();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Artikel telah di buat !');
        redirect('admin/artikel/index', 'refresh');
    } else {
        // konfigurasi ckfinder dengan ckeditor
        $this->load->library('ckeditor');
        $this->load->library('ckfinder');
        $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url() . 'asset/ckeditor/';
        $this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = 'Full';
        $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'en';
        $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor, '../../../asset/ckfinder/');

        $data['title'] = "Tambah Artikel";
        $data['main'] = 'admin/artikel/artikel_buat';
        $data['jurnal'] = $this->MJurnal->getJurnalDropDown();
        $data['kategori'] = $this->MKategori->getKategoriDropDown();
        $this->load->vars($data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/template');
    }
}
```

What should I add to my controller and my model, that would make the results in my table looks like this

```
IDPengarang     IDArtikel       nama_pengarang
1               1               testing 1
2               1               testing 2
3               1               testing 3
```

thank's before

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I want to enter the third form with 'IDArtikel' the same, but the author's name will be different

Comment: That's what you *want*. What you have you actually *tried*?

Comment: what code u wrote till now show that

Comment: the code in my model....

Comment: I think this code should be in your controller and it's good.......whats wrong and where you are getting error. Did you debugg your code

Comment: You asked this question already yesterday and what you are trying by your self.

Comment: i dont understand what are you doing ?

Comment: use loop and implode of php. that's what i can suggest after your unclear question